# sent international phone from jquery to codeigniter controller is sent null?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

my HTML code

```
<form  class="form" id="d_personal_form" action="<?php echo base_url('registerdoctor');?>"  method="post">
    <input type="tel" id="d_phone">
    <button class="btn" type="submit" id="d_send_personal_data">send</button>
</form>
```

javascript code

```js
 <script>
var input = document.querySelector("#d_phone");
var output = document.querySelector("#d_phone_error_msg");
var iti=intlTelInput(input, {
    allowDropdown: true,
    initialCountry: "auto",
    nationalMode: true,
    preferredCountries: ['ye'],
    utilsScript: "assets/js/utils.js?"
    });
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#d_send_personal_data").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"<?php echo base_url();?>doctor_c/register_doctor",
            data:{d_phone:iti.getNumber()},
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(iti.getNumber());           
                alert('true data ...');
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('something went wrong...');
            } 
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

my codeigniter controller code

```
$phone= $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('d_phone'));echo $phone;
```

the controller does not display any value, thanks alot for any help

Comment: i hope there is error in this line `data:{d_phone:iti.getNumber()}`

Comment: javascript code is run correctly and display the chosen phone number by alert function, the problem when sending the value to the controller no find any value

Comment: Can u just try as static `data:{d_phone:'123'}`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution by adding in view as HTML code

```
<input type="hidden" id="d_mobile" name="d_mobile" value="">
```

and edit JavaScript as

```
<script>
    var input = document.querySelector("#d_phone");
    var output = document.querySelector("#d_phone_error_msg");
    var iti=intlTelInput(input, {
        allowDropdown: true,
        initialCountry: "auto",
        nationalMode: true,
        preferredCountries: ['ye'],
        utilsScript: "assets/js/utils.js?"
        });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#d_send_personal_data").click(function(){
            var mobile =iti.getNumber();
            $('#d_mobile').val(mobile);                
        });
    });
    </script>
```

In the controller, I received a value of the hidden input as this

```
$phone= $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('d_mobile'));echo $phone;
```

It is sent the values in correctly

Answer (score 0):

Usually I get both the country code and dial code by:

1. Adding hidden inputs for both dial code and country code.
2. Adding 'countrychange' event listener to the input of type "tel".
3. Simply read the value of input element.

Inside your html file:

```
<input name="d_mobile" id="d_mobile" type="tel">
<input type="hidden" id="d_dial_code" name="d_dial_code" readonly>
<input type="hidden" id="d_country_code" name="d_dial_code" readonly>
```

Inside your js file:

```
var d_mobile = document.querySelector("#d_mobile");
var d_dial_code = document.querySelector("#d_dial_code");
var d_country_code = document.querySelector("#d_country_code");

var d_country_code_picker = intlTelInput(d_mobile, {
    initialCountry: "auto", 
    geoIpLookup: function(success){
        $.get("https://ipapi.co/json/", undefined, "json")
        .done(function(response){
            success(response.country);
        });
    },
    utilsScript: "assets/js/utils.js"
});

d_mobile.addEventListener('countrychange', function(e) {
    d_dial_code.value = d_country_code_picker.getSelectedCountryData().dialCode;
    d_country_code.value = d_country_code_picker.getSelectedCountryData().iso2;
});

//Get the value of dial code, country code, and mobile number:
//.......
    d_dial_code: $("#d_dial_code").val(),
    d_country_code: $("#d_country_code").val(),
    d_mobile: $("#d_mobile").val(),
//.......
```